# get all folders (os.walk) that are older than x days, delete

Tags: python

How can I concisely express "get all folders older than x days"

I have a method getOldDirs(dirPath, olderThanDays), it must walk through a given root folder and return a list of folders that are older than say 7 days.

I call the above function from another function cleanOldFolders(). cleanOldFolders() will delete those folders similar to "rm -Rf

code that I have, how can I modify the loops concisely:

```
"""
Clean oldFolders
"""
def cleanOldFolders(self):
    pathString = self.folderRoot + '/' + self.configMode + '/' + self.appId
    oldDirList = self.getOldDirs(pathString, 7);
    # Notify user that the following folders are deleted

    # remove all old dirs perhaps using shutil.removetree for each folder oldDirList, rm -Rf

    return
```

Get old dirs:

```
"""
get all subfolders under dirPath older than olderThanDays
"""
def getOldDirs(self,dirPath, olderThanDays):
    # What is the concise way of expressing Get me list of all dir/subdirs from "dirPath" that are older than "olderThanDays"
    # I know I have to use os.walk,
    # I want a concise loop like this - but should recurse using os.walk
    a = [os.path.join(dirPath, myfile) for myfile in os.listdir(dirPath)
            if (os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirPath, myfile)) and
                (self.isOlder(os.path.join(dirPath, myfile), olderThanDays))
        )]

#  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirPath):
#      for name in dirs:
#          print os.path.join(root, name)

    return a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the nice things about `os.walk()` is that it does the recursing for you. For its usage in your application it's important to specify the optional keyword argument ***topdown*** as `False` because its default is `True` and `os.rmdir()` won't delete non-empty directories.

This means your code will need to delete all the files and subdirectories in each subdirectory it encounters *before* removing the subdirectory itself. To facilitate doing that, the directory list `getOldDirs()` returns should be in the order that the subdirectories need to be deleted in.

It's also important to note that in the following, the directory's age is calculated in fractional, not whole, days, which means that seconds count and that one that was only say, 6 days and 23 hours and 59 seconds old won't get put on the list to be deleted even though it is only two seconds away from being old enough.

```
import os
import time

def getOldDirs(self, dirPath, olderThanDays):
    """
    return a list of all subfolders under dirPath older than olderThanDays
    """
    olderThanDays *= 86400 # convert days to seconds
    present = time.time()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirPath, topdown=False):
        for name in dirs:
            subDirPath = os.path.join(root, name)
            if (present - os.path.getmtime(subDirPath)) > olderThanDays:
                yield subDirPath
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be a starting point.

```
import os
from time import time as _time

SEVEN_DAYS = 60*60*24*7

def get_old_dirs(dir_path, older_than=SEVEN_DAYS):
    time_now = _time()
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for folder in folders:
            folder_path = os.path.join(path, folder)
            if (time_now - os.path.getmtime(folder_path)) > older_than:
                yield folder_path

list_of_folders = list(get_old_dirs("/some/path"))
```

Also, if you don't want to walk into folders that are older than `older_than` days (because you're going to delete them) you can prune the search tree be removing folder names from the `folders` list

```
def get_old_dirs(dir_path, older_than=SEVEN_DAYS):
    time_now = _time()
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for folder in folders[:]:
            folder_path = os.path.join(path, folder)
            if (time_now - os.path.getmtime(folder_path)) > older_than:
                yield folder_path
                folders.remove(folder)
```

Comment: +1 for the first approach. The second approach is interesting too, but can be improved by replacing `old_folders` by a `set()` and `discard`-ing the folders processed. That's what sets are for :)

Comment: Thanks - I just changed it to a set a few minutes ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

This uses os.walk and gets you the list of files older than 7 days

```
import os
from datetime import date

old_dirs = []
today = date.today()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
    for name in dirs:
        filedate = date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, name)))
        if (today - filedate).days > 7:                                            
            old_dirs.append(name)
```