# How To Archive Folders that are more than 30 days old with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import glob
from datetime import date, timedelta
import re
from time import gmtime, strftime

folder = 'PATH'
files = ['FileA.txt', 'Spare Original Config.dir']
archivePeriod = 0  # archive period in days

for file in files :
    try :
        # Remove file if older than archive period
        [fn, ff] = file.split('.')  # filename, fileformat
        for archivedFile in glob.glob(fn + "*" + ff):  # Find archived files
            matches = re.search(('(?<={}_)\d+(?=.txt)').format(fn), archivedFile)
            if  matches:
                if matches.group(0) < strftime('%Y%m%d' ,(date.today()-timedelta(days=archivePeriod)).timetuple()):
                    os.remove(os.path.join(dir, archivedFile))
```

Currently i am only able to archive file by file and looking for how to archive by folder

Comment: I recommend using pathlib objects. First it is safer to ask for file extension, second pathlib  objects have a `stat` method which "returns a os.stat_result object containing information about this path, like os.stat()". It also returns information for a file.

Comment: Have a look at `os.wak`  The accepted answer here may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769008/get-all-folders-os-walk-that-are-older-than-x-days-delete